# How to set current value of a sequence as default value?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, default, default-value

I know how to set a sequence as the default value:

```
ALTER TABLE TableA
ADD CONSTRAINT SequenDefault
DEFAULT NEXT VALUE FOR SeqA
FOR ColumnA
```

I also know how to get the current sequence value:

```
SELECT current_value 
FROM sys.sequences 
WHERE name = 'SeqA';
```

But how can I "put it together"?

Namely, set current value (not next value) of `SeqA` as the default value of `ColumnA` in `TableA`.

PS. This is the sequence if needed:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE SeqA AS int START WITH 1;
```

Thank you very much for your help!

**Update**

@marc_s said it is impossible to do such a thing, and @PanagiotisKanavos had mentioned [Change Tracking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/track-changes/about-change-tracking-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15), but before I figure out what it does, I still like to know if such thing is possible.

Say if I have a name table

```
CREATE TABLE NameTable
(
    ID int PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT NEXT VALUE FOR SeqA,
    Name nvarchar(50)
);
```

This table will "never" be updated! So a user who had already acquired the table (and saved) has "no need" to get the old record anymore whatsoever.

So I want to save the last record the user had downloaded in another table:

```
CREATE TABLE UserTable
(
    ID int IDENTIFY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    Age int,
    LastNameID int DEFAULT ???    --Don't know how to do it.
)
```

So I could let the user download the "new names only" by something like:

```
SELECT Name FROM NameTable LEFT JOIN UserTable ON NameTable.ID > UserTable.LastNameID WHERE UserTable.ID=19;
```

And a new user's `LastNameID` is "automatically" set to the current value of `SeqA` (upon downloading all names).

I know I could get it done by a stored procedure, but I still like to know if such a thing is possible, by simply setting a default value or something.

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: You cannot set the "current" value of a sequence as your default - what exactly the "current" value would be, is up for debate - you can **only** refer to the **next value** of a sequence, reliably

Comment: @marc_s OH! What a shame! But thanks!

Comment: Wouldn't make sense to make the **current** value of the sequence your default anyway, since that value has **already been assigned** to some row.....

Comment: Please share the definition of your sequence.

Comment: @Noob002 what are you trying to do? What you ask isn't useful. What is the *actual* problem that would be solved by knowing the current value?

Comment: @Noob002 if you want to return the value assigned to a field you can use the `OUTPUT` clause in `INSERT` or `DELETE`.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I'm just trying to record "the last record" a user has, to make sure "anything added after his/her last login will be updated to him/her".

Comment: So you want the last value used by that user, not the current value. As I said, the `INSERT` and `UPDATE` commands have an `OUTPUT` clause that can return the new values, including defaults. On the other hand, what you want to do is already available in SQL Server through [Change Tracking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/track-changes/about-change-tracking-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15). SQL Server can track not only insertions and modifications but deletions as well, without having to use key values or change fields

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos OK, thanks! I'll dig into it!

Comment: @lptr If I do that, the sequence will be incremented every time a new record is created or something, which is NOT what I want. I want the value to stay the same no matter how many records had been created. The sequence will be incremented "only" when a record of that specific table using that sequence is created.

Comment: @lptr I'm sorry I'm afraid that I can not understand what you mean.

Comment: You could do it with a trigger, but ***you should not do it***.  The whole point of sequences is that they are unique.  If you set a column to `current_value` then *you are re-using an existing sequence number*.  And if you are thinking that this is some clever way of doing foreign key insertion, I can promise you that it is very unreliable for that purpose and not recommended, *because you cannot guarantee that the current_value was not created by a different user/session* who happened to be running at the same time.

Comment: @RBarryYoung I'm not "reusing" an existing sequence, I just want to know "what the last record a user had downloaded", and I wish to "set it automatically", instead of updating it manually. Please see my update.

Comment: The original question was about getting this information from the `sys.sequences` table as a default value.  The point of my comment is that you should not try to use `sys.sequences` in this way because (for a variety of reasons) it is not reliable for this purpose.  There are ways that the `current_value` in `sys.sequences` *may not even be an actual ID value in the Names table* (because IDs have to be created before SQL Server knows for sure if they are actually going to be committed vs rolled-back).  The SOP way to get this is to query data tables, *not* the metadata.

Comment: @RBarryYoung OH! I get what you mean! I had totally forgotten that it could happen, thanks for your reminder!

Comment: @Noob002 And that's only one of the 4 or 5 different problems with it.